# ios Ad hoc distribution

Tags: php, ios, iphone, web-services, ios8

I have created .ipa file with xcode6 then extracted the .plist and .mobileprovision file with php coding and then generated the url and after a hit that url generates this warning...

**Warning:**  the app is not connected to url = itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://mashcharting.com/scdev1/IPA-Distribution-master2/files/cConnects/cConnects.plist

I want to know
 Does Ad hoc distribution is possible with xcode6 generated ipa file? 
 and if possible then what should be the appropriate procedure to do this

I have gone through number of links but it was all in vain....

Comment: Are you trying to download the IPA by clicking on a url on a server?

Comment: yes 
i am trying to download the app by clicking on url ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to download IPA via a url:

create a html file and put this code in:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://xxxxx.com/yyy/manifest.plist"> Download app by clicking here
```

manifest.plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://xxxxx.com/yyy/ipaname.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>bundleid.com</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0.4</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>appname</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

html file, manifest file & the IPA should be in same folder to make it easy

just open the html file, click the link should be good to go

Comment: After this the following warning generates

There is no application set to open the URL itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://smashchart.com/scdev1/test/cConnects.plist.

Comment: and my ipa flie is cConnects.ipa